# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Collection' of undefined discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

im cannot run the script becauce i get the error: 
*TypeError: Cannot read property 'Collection' of undefined*

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { Client, Util, MessageEmbed, discord} = require("discord.js");
const prefix = (process.env.DISCORD_PREFIX);
const { Player } = require('discord-player');
const bot = new Client({
    disableMentions: "all"
});


bot.player = new Player(bot);
bot.emotes = require('./config/emojis.json');
bot.filters = require('./config/filter.json');
bot.on('message', message => {
    bot.commands = new discord.Collection()();;
});
```

Please Help me:(
*(with example please)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create another costant like this `const Discord = require('discord.js')` and change
`new discord.Collection()` to `new Discord.Collection()`